# JavaScript animation(tiles)

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have code that fills the browser window with red tiles. 
This script is looking for a diagonal, and should change the color of each diagonal in turn with a slight delay. That is, first the left upper tile becomes a different color, then the diagonal goes on, etc.

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tile {
  background-color: #993333;
  border: 1px solid #661111;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 5vh;
  width: 5vw;
  float: left;
}
```

```js
var totalRows = 20;
var totalCols = 20;
var delay = 0.5; // задержка

var tiles = createTiles(totalRows, totalCols);
var diagonals = getDiagonals(tiles, totalRows, totalCols);


function getDiagonals(array, rows, cols) {
    var diagonals = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows + cols - 1; i++) {
        var row = 0;
        var col = i;
        var diagonal = [];
        while (col >= 0 && row < rows) {
            if (col < cols) {
                diagonal.push(array[row * cols + col]);
            }
            row++;
            col--;
        }
        diagonals.push(diagonal);
    }
    return diagonals;
}

function createTiles (rows, cols) {
    var tilesHtml = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
        tilesHtml += '<div class="tile"></div>';
    }
    var tiles = document.getElementById('tiles');
    tiles.innerHTML = tilesHtml;
    return tiles.querySelectorAll('.tile');
}
```

```html
<div id="tiles"> </div>
```

I do not know how to make a delay, I tried to implement it through a cycle, but nothing came of it, because they immediately change color without animation.

```
for (var i = 0; i < diagonals.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < diagonals[i].length; j++) {
    var tile = diagonals[i][j];

    tile.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}
```

I know that this can be implemented using setTimeout, but I do not know how to do this for a two-dimensional array.
It is necessary that the operation of the code be similar to this.
1111 | 0111 | 0011 | 0001 | 0000 | 0000 | 0000 | 0000
1111 | 1111 | 0111 | 0011  | 0001 | 0000 | 0000 | 0000
1111 | 1111 | 1111 | 0111  | 0011  | 0001 | 0000 | 0000
1111 | 1111 | 1111 | 1111  | 0111   | 0011 | 0001 | 0000
The code should work in such a way that during one cycle of passage one diagonal is completely colored (not on one slab, but on all tiles diagonally).

Comment: Did you try using a setTimeout for the delay? check this here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

[Something like this](https://codepen.io/Rahul_V7/pen/GYdWJa?editors=0010)?

To implement the *timed for-loop concept*, you have to use **recursion**. The following code-snippet illustrates it:

```
// Consider it as timed for(var i = 0; i < diagonals.length; i++) loop
function recursiveLoop1(i) {
  var j = 0; // initializtion

  if(i < diagonals.length) setTimeout(() => {
    recursiveLoop2(j, diagonals[i][j]); // called secondary for loop
    i++; // increment

    return recursiveLoop1(i); // called primary for loop after 100 ms
  }, 100);

  else return ; // exit condition
}

// Consider it as timed for(var j = 0; j < diagonals[i].length; j++) loop
function recursiveLoop2(j, el) {
  if(j < diagonals[i].length) setTimeout(() => {
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    j++; // increment

    return recursiveLoop2(j, el); // called secondary for loop after 100 ms
  }, 100);

  else return ; // exit condition
}

var i = 0; // initialization
recursiveLoop1(i);
```